# Save the Path2D as a .PNG or .JPEG from .to_planar() function of Trimesh Module in Python

Tags: python, drawing2d, trimesh

My main aim is to get the Drawing views of a STL file. I have tried the SolidWorks Method of converting a STL file to SLDPRT and then take the drawing views, but the drawing views in that case contains a lot of noise and is not accurate. SO, I am trying the Trimesh module. So far, with

```
slicex = meshx.section(plane_origin=meshx.centroid, plane_normal=[0,0,30])
slice_2D, to_3D = slicex.to_planar()
slice_2D.show()
```

and by changing the Plane_normal array values, I get the required cross section (which is somewhat similar to the three views), but I do not know how to save the image shown in the Console of Spyder as JPEG or PNG. I need the drawing views for further image analysis.

Any leads on this method or any other method to get the drawing views would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best results I've seen for this is using matplotib and saving a scatter plot.  You are able to adjust the resolution or save as a vector once it is in that format:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
slicex = meshx.section(plane_origin=meshx.centroid, plane_normal=[0,0,30])
slice_2D, to_3D = slicex.to_planar()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
_ = ax.scatter(slice_2D.vertices[:,0], slice_2D.vertices[:,1], color='lightgray')
ax.axis('off')
plt.savefig('meshx_slice.png')
```

More details on the file format and options are [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig).  This also works well for saving a full 2D mesh or a planar view of a 3D mesh, using the Trimesh.vertices as points.

ALTERNATIVE

If you're wanting to replicate what `slice_2D.show()` does, you can just borrow from [its code](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/master/trimesh/path/path.py#L1436) (which uses matplotlib):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# keep plot axis scaled the same
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
# hardcode a format for each entity type
eformat = {'Line0': {'color': 'g', 'linewidth': 1},
       'Line1': {'color': 'y', 'linewidth': 1},
       'Arc0': {'color': 'r', 'linewidth': 1},
       'Arc1': {'color': 'b', 'linewidth': 1},
       'Bezier0': {'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 1},
       'Bezier1': {'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 1},
       'BSpline0': {'color': 'm', 'linewidth': 1},
       'BSpline1': {'color': 'm', 'linewidth': 1}}
for entity in slice_2D.entities:
    # if the entity has it's own plot method use it
    if hasattr(entity, 'plot'):
        entity.plot(slice_2D.vertices)
        continue
    # otherwise plot the discrete curve
    discrete = entity.discrete(slice_2D.vertices)
    # a unique key for entities
    e_key = entity.__class__.__name__ + str(int(entity.closed))

    fmt = eformat[e_key].copy()
    if hasattr(entity, 'color'):
        # if entity has specified color use it
        fmt['color'] = entity.color
    plt.plot(*discrete.T, **fmt)
    plt.savefig('meshx_slice.png')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried the code. Unfortunately, I do not get the image as I require. Instead of straigt lines, I get dots in patches. I wanted to attach pictures to exaplin it more clearly, but I am unable to do it.

Comment: @Ad23 I added an update that shows what `slice_2D.show()` actually uses, and you can just save from there.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve my problem. Is there any general way of saving whatever is displayed on the console as a picture?

Comment: @Ad23 I would post that as a separate question, but I think it just depends on what tool you're using to display. You can always use `savefig` with matplotlib. Most plots can be replicated in plotly, which good exporting, too.